# Heroku doesn't find css with stylesheet_tag command (works locally)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

This is the line on the application.html.erb file
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag  yield(:css), media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
and css loads the filename required for each different page.

The resultant in the local server works wonderfully, in Heroku the css providad by that commands throws "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."

Just in case I tried precompiling the assets. Thanks for replying in advance, I'll proceede to show the logs:

```
C:\Sites\rankthisup>heroku run rake assets:precompile
Running `rake assets:precompile` attached to terminal... up, run.4248

C:\Sites\rankthisup>heroku logs
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/allrankings.css"):
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339460+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.339851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:15:15.340004+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:15:15.709491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favico
n.ico host=rankthisup.herokuapp.com fwd="200.81.44.68" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms se
rvice=8ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-07-28T03:21:46.287023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favico
n.ico host=rankthisup.herokuapp.com fwd="200.81.44.68" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms se
rvice=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-07-28T03:21:49.857863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/styles
heets/categories.css host=rankthisup.herokuapp.com fwd="200.81.44.68" dyno=web.1
 connect=1ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=1351
2013-07-28T03:21:49.851502+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/stylesheets/categorie
s.css" for 200.81.44.68 at 2013-07-28 03:21:49 +0000
2013-07-28T03:21:49.851575+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/stylesheets/categorie
s.css" for 200.81.44.68 at 2013-07-28 03:21:49 +0000
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/categories.css"):
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852815+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [
GET] "/stylesheets/categories.css"):
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.852999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853158+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853930+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:49.853687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-07-28T03:21:50.724700+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favico
n.ico host=rankthisup.herokuapp.com fwd="200.81.44.68" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms se
rvice=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-07-28T03:22:34.593098+00:00 heroku[run.1552]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2013-07-28T03:22:34.571741+00:00 heroku[run.1552]: Process exited with status 0
2013-07-28T03:22:57.340524+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake assets:precompile` by myxoh10@gmail.com
2013-07-28T03:23:01.652538+00:00 heroku[run.4248]: Awaiting client
2013-07-28T03:23:01.698517+00:00 heroku[run.4248]: Starting process with command
 `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
2013-07-28T03:23:02.879867+00:00 heroku[run.4248]: State changed from starting t
o up
2013-07-28T03:23:10.507117+00:00 heroku[run.4248]: Process exited with status 0
2013-07-28T03:23:10.524617+00:00 heroku[run.4248]: State changed from up to comp
lete
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that categories.css isn't on the compile list. You might try something like this in config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['categories.css']
```

Substitute whatever the actual filename is (maybe it's categories.sass).

Comment: Nope, added that to the file, commited, pushed to heroku, re runned the assets:precompile. Nothing changed.